# when add a file to staged area, does git save the directory info?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-add

I am curious about git add action,
so I do some test.

create a index

```
1. git init
2. mkdir mydir
3. echo "hello" > mydir/hello
4. find .git/objects  ==> nothing 
5. git add .
6. find .git/objects ==> only find one file ,by cat-file,  I am sure it is hello
```

do some change

```
7. rm mydir/hello
```

get the file back

```
8. git checkout mydir/hello
9. ls mydir/hello ==> hello is back
```

My doubt is:
when I do `'git add .'`,there create only one blob, and not create a tree to record the direcoty 'mydir'. So,how could `git checkout mydir/hello` can find the blob ?

Comment: I believe the trees are constructed in `.git/index` alone as that’s often something that will change before the commit is actually made.

Comment: You might find the section in the Pro Git book on the ["Git Internals"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) interesting, particularly "Tree Objects". It seems to go over the storage of git fairly well.

Comment: Git Internal just gives an example without directory. It does not explain in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git` index does not create tree objects, internally or externally.  Directory structures are represented within the filenames of the blobs they contain, until a commit (and its associated tree object) is made.

So in your example the file's name is literally represented as `mydir/hello` and is associated with the blob you saw.

([Source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9bea2b5896701cf952f75c8f6756656cd3c40af0/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt))